# How to initiate download of mp4 from url (and prevent the mp4 from playing in the browser)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to initiate the download of an mp4 file that is located at a url (I do not have access to the file itself).  I do not want the video to play in the browser, and I do not want the user to have to leave the web page.

I have tried creating an `<a>` element and using the download attribute, but it has to be compatible with IE, which doesn't support the download attribute, so that is not viable.

I have tried `window.open('https://example.com/file-name.mp4');`, but some browsers will simply start playing the video in a new tab instead of downloading it.

I have also tried `window.open('https://mywebsite.com/download.php?file-id');` where the download.php file checks to make sure the user is authorized to download the file, formats the url, sets Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers, and ends with `readfile($file_url);`.  This works well except, on failure, the download.php page remains open.  I would rather be able to display an error message on the original page than have to set up an error page for download.php.

I tried to use the above method with an AJAX call to avoid the redirect problem, but I cannot figure out how to take the response and start the download with it.

How can I initiate the download of the mp4 file without the chance of it playing in the browser or redirecting to another web page?

Comment: On your PHP main page you could do the processing to validate and output any errors. And if no errors, provide the link to download.php. But don't remove the error processing from download.php. So that way they only see the errors on the main page before given access to download, BUT the download.php still does processing just in case someone creates the URL themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$file = 'file-name.mp4';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    if(!readfile($file)) {
       echo "error occured!";
    }
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Error file not found";
}
?>
```